# how to generate smime with file attachenment (eg, csv , pdf ) through openssl

Tags: openssl

I could able to generate SMIME content through openssl without any file attachment.

But i need to generate SMIME content with file attachment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a tool like [`makemime`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/makemime) to generate a MIME message of type `multipart/mixed` that includes your text message and attached files as MIME components.

You would then pipe that plaintext `multipart/mixed` message through `openssl smime` to turn it into an S/MIME message.

Comment: Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="------2DF0A5783DE2299E9E0093BF7264BF53"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename ="sucess.aps"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;  name="success.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

....

------A0CB636B903D9329C594C6F0DC74343D
Content-type: text/plain

Test

------A0CB636B903D9329C594C6F0DC74343D

Comment: Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="------2DF0A5783DE2299E9E0093BF7264BF53"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename ="sucess.aps"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;  name="success.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

....

------A0CB636B903D9329C594C6F0DC74343D
Content-type: text/plain

Test

------A0CB636B903D9329C594C6F0DC74343D

i used multipart/mixed message to generate SMIME. i could not get correct output. Could you please explain me in detail.